# Checkbox Not Responding

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

1)How do I select multiple checkbox and submit to get the input.I clicked "Compare" but nothing happens

2)How do I set how many number of checkbox are allowed?For example,before each "Compare" I want maximum of 3 checkbox only.

3)How do I clear the output for another round after done comparing?

```
<!DOC HTML>
<html>
<TITLE></TITLE>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('input[type="compare"]').click(function () {
               $('.frame-wrapper').eq( $(this).index() -1 ).fadeIn();
            });

        });

    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
        .frame-wrapper {
            display: none;
            float: left;
            width: 32%;
            margin-top: 20px;
            margin-right: 1%;
            background-color: #eee;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <b>Please select an option</b>
    A <input type="checkbox" name="Option" />
    B <input type="checkbox" name="Option" />
    C <input type="checkbox" name="Option" />
    D <input type="checkbox" name="Option" />
    E <input type="checkbox" name="Option" />
    F <input type="checkbox" name="Option" />
    <input type="submit" value="Compare"/>
    <input type="reset" name="clear" value="Clear"/>

    <div style="clear: both;"></div>
    <div id="tblA" class="frame-wrapper">
        You selected A
    </div>
    <div id="tblB" class="frame-wrapper">
        You selected B
    </div>
    <div id="tblC" class="frame-wrapper">
        You selected C
    </div>
    <div id="tblD" class="frame-wrapper">
        You selected D
    </div>
    <div id="tblE" class="frame-wrapper">
        You seleted E
    </div>

    <div id="tblF" class="frame-wrapper">
        You selected F
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `$('input[type="compare"]')`, you don't have any input type of `compare`. Also giving a same name to all checkboxes is not a good idea (this trick is rather used with a group of radio buttons).

Comment: Because my intention was to let user to tick max of 3 checkbox,after clicking compare it will bring out the content from each checkbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code:

```
$('input[type="submit"]').click(function () {
    if($('input[name=Option]:checked').length >2)
    {
         $('.frame-wrapper').fadeOut();
    $('input[name=Option]').each(function() {
        if ($(this).prop("checked"))
        {
            $('.frame-wrapper').eq( $(this).index() -1 ).fadeIn();
        }                            
    });  
    }
    else
      {
         alert("check count");
      }
});
```

Comment: where can I alert user that he/she has reached maximum number of checkbox can be checked which is 3?

Comment: Then we need to write separate jquery to capture click event of the checkbox and use the same checked length logic to alert the user

Answer (score 0):

`$('input[type="compare"]').`

You are selecting type=compare, you want to select the submit-button, type=submit.

Also, you should use radio buttons if you are supposed to pick only one option.